# GUI application haven't enough permissions to open /opt

Tags: permissions, gui

1. I logged to ubuntu (22.04) in with an admin `my_user`.
2. Made `chown` to
   `my_user` for `/opt`, checked from folder explorer `my_user` is able to read/write to `/opt`.
3. Installed a GUI application (postman)
   under `my_user` using sudo.

Wanna use it and open some file via file dialog from `/opt` directory. Got `permission denied` while browsing from inside the GUI application (postman).

Doesn't a launched GUI application has the same permissions? When I see `home` folder from file dialog inside the GUI application (postman) I see home directory for user `177`, does it mean the application is started under some temporary user with no permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You are not following conventions by trying to save data under `/opt` in the first place. So the general advise is to organize your storage elsewhere in the file system, although in Linux anything is possible, also not following the conventions.

That aside, a user of any application that is not confined ("sandboxed") should be able to save in any directory where permissions and ownership allows. An additional requirement is that the directory can be reached: any directories leading to that directory should have the "executable" bit allowed for that user (by default, that permission is set open for anyone). So if that did not work for you, you may not have correctly done what you described you did.

A GUI application normally launched as the user who launches it. In principle, applications can be setup to run parts as a different user, but that happens if there are specific requirements. e.g. graphical system tools may at some point ask your password to assume root permissions for specific processes. In the old days, the entire GUI application would be run as user `root`, but that is not anymore considered best practice.